# Codeigniter base_url() not working properly

Tags: codeigniter, url, hyperlink, uri

i have set my `base_url()` like this

```
  $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Now the problem is all links works fine if there is no `www` before the url. But if try to access website using `www` before the url like `http://www.example.com/` than the `base_url()` is not working. If i add `www` in the `base_url()` than the links without `www` does not work.

My .htaccess is as follows,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you show us your .htaccess? The issue is almost certainly from there

Comment: CI tries to auto detect the protocol, base_url right? why not leave it blank?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067238/codeigniter-base-url-doesnt-seem-to-be-working

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to application/config/autoload.php and then do this change

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 1):

go to application >> config >> autoload.php

and add

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also in your controller.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```