# Codeigniter wont load css form file

Tags: css, codeigniter

k so i have all my css in separate files but it wont load, i have it in a folder called css in the root directory and have separate css files for each view. it does load on the home page but none of the others.

This is the code that i have tried in my views in the header tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/(name of file for specific view).css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/(name of file for specific view).css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url() ?>css/about.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url('css/about.css') ?>" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url().'css/about.css' ?>" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url().'/css/about.css' ?>" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'css/about.css' ?>" />
```

the path to my css from root is: /css/(file name).css

the path to my view from root is: /applications/view/(file name).php

what am i doing wrong?

i am running codeigniter 2.1.3 with mod_rewrite

Edit:

This is source code from browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>The Groundscore Way</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/about.css" />


</head>
<body>

<div class='site'>

    <div class='ban' >
        <img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/gs_banner_med.JPEG" />
    </div>

    <div class='map'>
        <BR /><BR /><BR /><BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/home" TITLE="home" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/home_0.png"></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/about" TITLE="about" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/about_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/members" TITLE="members" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/members_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/news" TITLE="members" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/news_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/blog" TITLE="blog" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/blog_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/projects" TITLE="projects" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/projects_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/portfolios" TITLE="portfolios" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/portfolios_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <A HREF="http://www.ground-score.com/main/contact"TITLE="contact" ><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/contact_0.png" /></A>
        <BR />
        <BR /><a href=http://www.ground-score.com/main/login><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/log_in_0.png" /></a><BR /><a href=http://www.ground-score.com/main/signup><img src="http://www.ground-score.com/imgs/sign_up_0.png" /></a><BR />        </div>


    <div class='content'>



</div>


    <div class=cpwrt>

        <P> <span style="color:#ffffff;"> Copyright (c) 2012 ground-score.com. All rights reserved.</span> </P>

    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

css file code:

```
        p 
{
    color:black;
    font-family:arial;
    line-height:130%;
}

body 
{
    background-image:url('/imgs/green_tex.jpg');
}

.ban
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:25%;
}
.map
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:5%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    width:130px;
    height:625px;
    padding:12px;
    border-width:1px;
    background:#9d1e15
}
h2
{
    text-align:center;
}
.content
{
    position:absolute;
    top:16%;
    left:25%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    padding:8px;
    border-width:1px;
    background:white;
    width:583px;
    height:542px;
}

.cpwrt
{
    position:absolute;
    top:97%;
    left:33%;

}

.site
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:1200px;
    height:690px;
}
```

Comment: what is the output in the browser? I'd assume this is a relative vs. absolute issue rather than a CodeIgniter issue. Do you have a url we could see?

Comment: it out puts ass if i added no css at all

Comment: each <div> stacked down the page. everything stacked the same in its <div>

Comment: We need to see the code that is generated - load the page, "view source", copy and paste relevant sections.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url().'/css/about.css' ?>" /> is what its from, but the effect is the same for all of them

Comment: When you say `root` are you talking about the `public_html` or one level above?  I do not believe you can access page assets outside of the `public_html` location.  So if the CI `/application/` directory is installed _outside_ of `public_html` and your `/css/` directory is in the same place, the browser will not be able to load the CSS file.

Comment: when i say root i mean the public_html folder: public_html/css/file : : public_html/applications/

Comment: Ok, `/public_html/` is the perfect place for the CSS files, but anywhere _inside_ `/public_html/` is not a very secure place for the CI application or system files.  I know it's nothing to do with your issue at hand, but thought you should know about this security issue.  [See this thread and scroll down to the "Application & System directory placement" section in the first posting](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/125687/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok it works now, the only way I got it to way to type `https://` and all `https://www.site.com/css/(file).css`

Answer (score 0):

Try `<?php echo base_url() . 'css/about.css' ?>`

If this doesn't work, I think it's likely that you don't actually have a file named "about.css" in your /css directory. http://www.ground-score.com/css/home.css works fine.  http://www.ground-score.com/css/about.css does not.

Comment: I don't see that listed.  You see that I added "echo", right?

Comment: Does it echo anything?  Have you used the base_url() function anywhere else in this project?

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067238/codeigniter-base-url-doesnt-seem-to-be-working

Comment: yes i have used it, it's echo: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ground-score.com/css/about.css" />, but it doesnt load the about.css script, also, now it doesnt load it on the homepage ether

Comment: Make sure you actually have a file called about.css in /css

Comment: A link to http://www.ground-score.com/css/home.css works fine, while  http://www.ground-score.com/css/about.css does not

Comment: maybe i should not include it in a separate file, it all worked before i tried to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20720/discussion-between-john-and-chris-herbert)

Comment: i typed "http:// www.ground-score.com/css/home.css" (with out space, that was so it would display here) and it worked